# Installing an Operating System onto Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hypervisor, microsoft

I have downloaded and installed **Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019** on a laptop, I am using **Hyper-V Manager** in **another laptop** and have created a virtual machine in the Hyper-V Server.

Now, how to provide the OS to the virtual machine as it is **neither reading a USB drive** nor I do have a **DVD of the OS** to load it into the Hyper-V server device

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ISO image of the OS install, you can attach that to the VM by creating a virtual storage controller and adding the ISO image to it.

If you don't have an ISO image and only what's on the USB flash drive, you can plug the flash drive into the physical VM host and under disk management, take that drive offline. Once it is offline, you can then add it to the virtual storage device and set that as your boot device.

Comment: The Microsoft Hyper-V Server does not have just more than a command line and does not read the USB drive.

Comment: Use the Virtual manager from the other laptop to get the GUI

Comment: Just prepare ISO image on your laptop, copy it to a folder inside Hyper-V server (via SMB) and add ISO image in Hyper-V Manager